# Adult talking in the 3rd person when talking about himself

Tags: personality, clinical-psychology, personality-disorder

> The therapist asked John "Tell me about yourself?"
>
> John  starting talking about himself, his upbringing and his family. However Instead of using the word "I" he mostly uses the word "He" in all his sentences
>
> When the therapist pointed this out to John he was unaware he was doing this and he didn't believe the therapist. John said he has permanent employment and someone at work would have pointed it out to him if he did this.
>
> What condition could John have? What does it say about John that he doesn't realize he is doing it.

Some answers I can think of

- He has an inferiority complex and speaks about himself in the 3rd person in order to distance/disassociate himself from the person who he is.
  Him not realizing it means he has been doing it for some significant time so that it has become second nature.
- he could have a fantasy prone personality which results in him losing touch with reality resulting in him seeing himself in the 3rd person like a computer game

What other possible answers could there be or where can I be pointed to do research on this condition?

Comment: Maybe he's got DIS. Look it up, I bet there's plenty of info on that topic.